# Fish: Concise way to output elements of list on separate lines

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I am wondering if there is a concise way to output the elements of a fish list on separate lines.

I know I can do e.g. `echo $PATH | tr ' ' '\n'` to achieve the desired output, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/games
/sbin
```

but this seems cumbersome. And I'm also guessing it will break if elements contain spaces. Is there a more concise, correct, and fish built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf "%s\n" $PATH` is what you're looking for.

It does respect elements with spaces:

```
$ set x "a b" "C d"
$ printf "%s\n" $x
a b
C d
```

Comment: Very nice; thank you!